# jQuery: Checking to see if list contains text, then redirect, else redirect here

Tags: jquery, redirect, if-statement

I'm a complete novice when it comes to jQuery, so please bear with me...

I have this HTML

```
<ul class="zoneSubscriptions">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="zoneName"><a href="/Default.aspx?PageID=8267303">My Account</a></li>
      <li>Never</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="zoneName"><a href="/Default.aspx?PageID=8269026">Practitioners Area</a></li>
      <li>Never</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If the link for Practitioners Area is present, redirect the browser to that href, else, redirect to the My Account section.

This is the jQuery I have...

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if(jQuery(".zoneName a").text() == 'Practitioners Area'){
        document.location.href = $(this).attr('href');

    }else{
        document.location.href = jQuery('.zoneName:first a').attr('href');
    };


});
```

When it runs, it just redirects me to the My Account, even though the Practioners Area is present.

I know I'm probably doing something really stupid... But can anyone help me and show me the light? Would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be wiser to do this server side and handle the redirection with http headers.

Comment: Yes, it would be, but using a CMS and as usual, there are limitations. That's why I'm resorting to jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the condition in your `if` statement to this:

```
$(".zoneName a:contains('Practitioners Area')").length
```

The problem with your attempt is that `jQuery(".zoneName a").text()` will return the text of all matched elements (in your case, it returns something like "My AccountPractioners Area"). This version checks to see if there are any matching elements containing the string "Practioners Area". Here's the full code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if($(".zoneName a:contains('Practitioners Area')").length) {
        document.location.href = $(this).attr('href');

    }else{
        document.location.href = jQuery('.zoneName:first a').attr('href');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var isPractitionersAreaPresent=false;
    jQuery(".zoneName a").text(function(i,v){
        if(v == 'Practitioners Area'){
            isPractitionersAreaPresent=true;
        }
    });
    if(isPractitionersAreaPresent){
        document.location.href = elem.attr('href');

    }else{
        document.location.href = jQuery('.zoneName:first a').attr('href');
    }
});
```

jQuery(".zoneName a").text() return the text value of all "a" elements in ".zoneName"